# registering servlet in OSGi that receives parameters

Tags: servlets, osgi

I'm trying to register a HttpServlet that will receive parameters (don't really care if it is via POST or GET, altough POST preferred obviously). Pretty much just extending what is depicted here:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-osgi3.html?page=3

And here:

http://www.peterfriese.de/osgi-servlets-a-happy-marriage/

I'm not using still declarative registration, first want to see it working, then I'll do the other stuff.

Doubt arises when calling:

```
httpService.registerServlet("/helloworld", new RestServlet(), null, null);
```

Not sure how to tell HttpService that the server will accept params. Besides, is it mandatory to create a HttpServlet with new() everytime a servlet is registered or can I reuse the same for different aliases? I'm asking because maybe it is possible to use some wildcard in the alias argument and then let the HttpServlet object deal with whatever comes in the HttpRequest...?

Any help/suggestions/thoughts are welcome!

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know very much about OSGI, however it seems to me to be more a pure servlet problem. I took a look at the links you provided and hope I can help you.

First, I think you do not need to tell the `HttpService` that it will accept params. When you use servlets, you can simply extract the request parameters:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getParameter(paramName); // get a request parameter
}
```

Second, I think you can use the same Servlet for multiple "aliases". This seems like a kind of servlet mapping to me: You can use multiple mappings (`/helloworld`, `/helloxyz` etc.) for one and the same servlet.

Comment: Ok, let's say I want to construct in the doGet method some HTML code with a URL link with some GET parameters, something like /hellowordl?message=whatever...how should I treat this when registering the HttpServlet? Because if I do so, then it seems not able to recognize what comes after the "?", thus not calling RestServlet.doGet method...

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized I had a typo on the HTML code generated in doGet...it seems to work now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

- You can register multiple times with the same servlet if you ignore the servlet init.
- If you want to see all, just register /
- The whiteboard is a lot easier and a much better approach.

The Http Service will find the longest path and call that servlet. So / is a fallback.

Example hello world servlet without whiteboard:

```
@Component
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rsp) throws IOException {
    rsp.getWriter().write( ("Hello World " + rq.getParameter("name")).getBytes());
  }

  @Reference
  void setHttp(HttpService http) { http.registerService("/hello", null, null); }
}
```

Example, now with whiteboard:

```
@Component(provide=Servlet.class, properties="alias=/hello")
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rsp) throws IOException {
    rsp.getWriter().write( ("Hello World " + rq.getParameter("name")).getBytes());
  }
```

}

This kind of things are really easy to play with in bndtools. Create a small project with DS, then create a bndrun file with the web console. Won't regret it.

Comment: Hello Peter, thanks for the detailed answer, but I'm a bit lost...what is bndtools and DS? I'm a newbie in this Servlet thingy...if I construct a URL with alias /hello?param=foo ...will this work? In my case, so far it hasn't, thus, I'm not sure how to register the Servlet so it is capable of handling GET params...

Comment: It sounds like you're confused on a basic level. the alias=/hello makes the servlet be called when you surf to http://localhost:8080/hello, which returns 'Hello World null'. If you surf to http://localhost:8080/hello?name='Peter', the servlet will receive the 'name' parameter, and return 'Hello World Peter'.

Comment: bndtools is an IDE for OSGi based on Eclipse, see http://bndtools.org DS is Declarative Services and you cannot live without those in OSGi. See http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html for an intro to DS and bndtools.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I got it wrong at a very basic level :) Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I'll check bndtools, although I'm more used to Eclipse...thanks!

Comment: bndtools is an eclipse plugin so you've all your goodies right there :-) bndtools replaces PDE, which is more oriented towards Eclipse plugin development instead of OSGi bundle development though these things are in theory the same. Just goto the Eclipse marketplace and search for bndtools.

Comment: Hey Peter, yeah, checking your website I saw that bndtools is available as a Eclipse Plug-in too. I'm downloading it as I write these lines. Will also follow some of the, by the way, great tutorials to see how to use DS. This looks promising!